# How to get a return true out of happy number algorithm?

Tags: javascript

The goal of this algorithm is to take the square of each digit of a number, add them together, and then keep repeating until the number `1` is returned. I've determined the algorithm works, however, I cannot get true to `return`. Why isn't this working?

```js
const n = 19;

const sumSquare = (n) => {
  const N = n.toString();
  let sum  =  0;
  for (let digit of N) {
      const product = +digit * +digit;
      sum += product;
  }  
  console.log(sum);
  if (sum === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    sumSquare(sum);
  }
};

console.log(sumSquare(n));
```

Comment: in your `else` you should `return sumSquare(sum);` I believe

Comment: btw, you could omit the unary pluses, because the multiplication operator vonverts every operand to number.

Comment: Return the `sumSquare` in else part. I feel that’s the missing part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `return sumSquare(sum);`, this will then finish with a return value of `true` as seen here:

```js
const n = 19;

const sumSquare = (n) => {
  const N = n.toString();
  let sum  =  0;
  for (let digit of N) {
      const product = +digit * +digit;
      sum += product;
  }  
  console.log(sum);
  if (sum === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return sumSquare(sum);
  }
};

console.log('result:', sumSquare(n));
```

---

We could also simplify that whole if statement to look like this:

```
return sum === 1 || sumSquare(sum);
```

```js
const n = 19;

const sumSquare = (n) => {
  const N = n.toString();
  let sum  =  0;
  for (let digit of N) {
      const product = +digit * +digit;
      sum += product;
  }  
  console.log(sum);
  return sum === 1 || sumSquare(sum);
};

console.log('result:', sumSquare(n));
```